# Twig shuffled array including duplicates when it shouldn't

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I have a simple array of values.  I need to output a "random" subset of its contents but without duplications. However, what I've got so far IS including duplicates.

The server does not have the Twig Array Extension installed so i don't have access to the Shuffle filter.

Oh, and if there's a better approach, I'm open to suggestions.

```
{% set arrImgs = {'0':'a','1':'b','2':'c','3':'d','4':'e','5':'f','6':'g','7':'h'} %}

{% set outputQty = 5 %}
{% set randomizedArr = [] %}  

{# create new array of randomly selected elements (just to shuffle the order)   
   and limit the result to outputQty #}
{% for i in 0..100 if  randomizedArr|length < outputQty %} 
    {% set tmpImg = [random(arrImgs)] %}
    {% if tmpImg not in randomizedArr %}
        {% set randomizedArr = randomizedArr|merge(tmpImg) %} 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %} 


{% for img in randomizedArr %}
    {{ img }}, 
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is an extension for this, I would suggest installing it if at all possible. Of course, I assume you would have just done that if it was.

Your code doesn't quite work as is, but will work with a couple of key tweeks.

```
{% set arrImgs = {'0':'a','1':'b','2':'c','3':'d','4':'e','5':'f','6':'g','7':'h'} %}

{% set outputQty = 5 %}
{% set randomizedArr = [] %}  

{# create new array of randomly selected elements (just to shuffle the order)   
   and limit the result to outputQty #}
{% for i in 0..100 if  outputQty < arrImgs|length and randomizedArr|length < outputQty %} 
    {% set tmpImg = random(arrImgs) %}
    {% if tmpImg not in randomizedArr %}
        {% set randomizedArr = randomizedArr|merge([tmpImg]) %} 
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %} 


{% for img in randomizedArr %}
    {{ img }}, 
{% endfor %}
```

Notice that I have added a check in the `for` loop that will make sure you don't create an infinite loop by requesting more unique items than the `arrImgs` array can provide. Also, your check was not working because your `randomizedArr` never contains any items that are hashes and you were `set`ing `tmpImg` to a hash containing the item you picked from `arrImgs`. By moving the transformation to a has to the actual `merge` call, this issue is solved.